# get next item in json string array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a loop that loops through each item in an array and populates a check box.

the identity alternates throughout the loop.

```
"[{\"NAME\":\"TOM, B\",\"ID\":\"222\"},{\"NAME\":\"joe\",\"ID\":\"202\"}]"
```

how can I get the text of the select box to be the ID and the Name to be the text.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function () {               
   $.each(this, function (key, value) {
     drname.options.add(new Option(value, value[+1])); 
    });
});
```

I tried the `[+1]` as I've seen in similar questions but no dice.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for that second `$.each`, just use the properties of the object directly without iterating through them:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function(){               
    drname.options.add(new Option(this.ID, this.NAME)); 
});
```

Depending on what order the `Option` constructor expects the argument, it could also be:

```
new Option(this.NAME, this.ID)
```

Comment: Thank you. A point worth mentioning... every time this function is called the options are appended to the list. For a second I thought something was wrong because my select box was three times longer than I expected. But that was only because I called the function three times. I used `$("selectBoxName").empty()` before the function to clear the options of the select box because in my situation the function may be called more than once with a json array.